# How to use the PWA file handler with Vue 3

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, progressive-web-apps, web-manifest

I would like to create a file with a custom file extension (.vc2d) that will open in my progressive web app. I am using Vue and Typescript, with `file_handlers` in my web manifest file, and `window.launchQueue` in my PWA. When I double click on the file in File Explorer, it launches the PWA correctly, but instead of passing the file data to my app, it passes an empty array.

**Web Manifest file**

```json
{
    "name": "MyApp",
    "scope": "/",
    "display": "standalone",
    "start_url": "https://www.myapp.com",
    "orientation": "any",
    "related_applications": [],
    "prefer_related_applications": false,
    "file_handlers": [
        {
            "action": "/",
            "accept": {
                "application/json": [
                    ".vc2d"
                ]
            },
            "icons": [
                {
                  "src": "assets/vc2d-icon.png",
                  "sizes": "256x256",
                  "type": "image/png"
                }
              ]
        },
        {
            "action": "/",
            "accept": {
                "image/svg+xml": [
                    ".svg"
                ]
            },
            "icons": [
                {
                  "src": "assets/svg-icon.png",
                  "sizes": "256x256",
                  "type": "image/png"
                }
              ]
        }
    ],
    "icons": []
}
```

**Vue Component**

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

declare global {
    interface Window {
        launchQueue: {
            setConsumer: (launchParams) => void;
        };
    }
}

export default defineComponent({
    name: "Home",
    components: { },
    data: function () {
        return { 
            //...
        };
    },
    mounted: function () {
        if ('launchQueue' in window) {
            console.log('File Handling API is supported!');

            window.launchQueue.setConsumer(async launchParams => {
                console.log('handling file', launchParams); // -->> launchParams.files is an empty array

                for (const file of launchParams.files) {
                    const blob = await file.getFile();
                    blob.handle = file;
                    const text = await blob.text();
                    var fileType: SupportedImportTypes;
                    if (/\.vc2d$/.test(file.name)) fileType = "vc2d";
                    else if (/\.svg$/.test(file.name)) fileType = "svg";
                    else return console.log("file extension not supported", file.name);
                    this.importFile(fileType, text, file);
                }
            });
        }
    },
    methods: {
        importFile: function (type: SupportedImportTypes, fileData?: string, fileDetails?: File) {
             //...
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Is `mounted` the correct place to put the file handler? Or am I doing async/await incorrectly? Or is the `file_handlers` API failing? Or something else

Answer (score 0):

The above code functions correctly, but when the app is installed in Edge, there are 2 versions of the PWA listed in the "Open with..." menu. One opens the file and the other one doesn't. Once I figured out which one works, I set it to always open my file type with that program, and it works now. Maybe this will help someone facing the same frustration